# Change font color letter by letter in one word on hover

Tags: css

I want to change the color of each letter in one word when mouse over happens.

I use transition for doing this but  I want this change to happen smoothly from left to right but I don't know why the ease-in timing function does not work. I want to change the color of my letters in such a way that div element moves.

The first one in this site is what I want:
http://tympanus.net/Development/TextStylesHoverEffects/

```
<style>
    p {
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation: mymove 5s infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

    .a:hover{
        color: cyan;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        from {
            left: 0px;
        }

        to {
            left: 200px;
        }
    }

    @keyframes mymove {
        from {
            left: 0px;
        }

        to {
            left: 200px;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>
    <p class="a">HelloGolnaz</p>

    <div></div>
</body>
```

Sorry if this is a simple question and thank you.

Comment: You'd have to create separate elements for each letter or use some JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two `div`s one over another to create such effect:

```css
.default,
.hover {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #787878;
}
.hover {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #050;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:hover .hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="default">SOME WORD HERE</div>
  <div class="hover">SOME WORD HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much,if i want to use this effect for my navigation bar items,i have to set left and top property for each item in class like hover?

Comment: @GolnazAsadollahzadeh Yes, but if all elements has same offset from `wrapper` than you can set it only once

Comment: What I was missing in my case was `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;`. Thanks, @Justinas

Answer (score 1):

First I want to say that [@justinas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692664/change-font-color-letter-by-letter-in-one-word-on-hover/38692888#38692888) is a correct answer but I just wanted to modify his answer a bit to make use of the [**`steps()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#The_steps()_class_of_timing-functions) function in CSS animation instead of CSS transition, so that it looks like it is being filled letter by letter.

Note that to simulate it the number of steps should be same as the number of letters

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mpnLj9oc/1/)

```css
.default,
.hover {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #787878;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.hover {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: navy;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper:hover .hover {
  width: 100%;
  animation: stagger 2s steps(14);
}
@keyframes stagger {
  from {width: 0;}
  to {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="default">SOME WORD HERE</div>
  <div class="hover">SOME WORD HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GolnazAsadollahzadeh, you're welcome, but I posted it just as a modified version of justinas's answer, that what I've said in my post, and I didn't want this answer to be the checked one, so would you please check justinas's answer back as the correct one.

Comment: thanks again @Mi-Creativity ,is there any way that i change the direction of changing the color?

Comment: so sorry @Mi-Creativity ,i am new in stack and i make mistake.

Comment: it's ok mate it wasn't a mistake at all, I just didn't want to get the credit out of his own work